# What is a list semanitcs in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

In context of the following para :

prs.slide_layouts is the collection of slide layouts contained in the presentation and **has list semantics,**
at least for item access which is about all you can do with that collection at the moment.

Comment: Has the same methods and/or behaviour as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *semantics* is sometimes used in a programming context to describe the set of behaviors an object has. So in this case, as Zero mentioned in his comment, it means *"has the same behaviors as a list"*.

You could alternately interpret the phrase as *"is a list-like thing"* or *"is interacted with the same way you would a list object"*.

The term semantics means "meaning". In the case of an object, its meaning comprises "what you can do with it" and how. In this case you can do "list-like" things with it, like iterate its members with `for x in xs`, get its length with `len(xs)`, and access elements by index with `xs[i]`.